How to deserialize boolean params.permit value correctly to make sure it's boolean in Rails
There are params to permit:
{
   "string_value": "value",
   "boolean_value": "true/false",
   "other_value": "blabla"
}

I need to convert the boolean_value to Boolean like this ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.deserialize but when I permit params:
ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.deserialize(params.permit(:boolean_value)[:boolean_value])

it doesn't work correctly because the result is always true.
How do I pass and permit this param correctly?

I am a bit confused are you saying the value of params[:boolean_value] is "true/false"; or is it either "true" or "false"?
As stated in the documentation for ActiveModel::Type::Boolean:

A class that behaves like a boolean type, including rules for coercion of user input.

"false", "f", "0", 0 or any other value in FALSE_VALUES will be coerced to false.
Empty strings are coerced to nil.
All other values will be coerced to true.


For Reference FALSE_VALUES is:
[ false, 0, "0", :"0", "f", :f, "F", :F, "false", :false, "FALSE", :FALSE, "off", :off, "OFF", :OFF]

The implementation is fairly straightforward Source
So if you are really passing "true/false" then the result will always be true.
Examples:
["true/false","true","false","", "other"].map do |value| 
 {value => ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.deserialize(value)}
end  
#=> [ {"true/false" => true},{"true" => true}, {"false" => false}, {"" => nil}, {"other" => true}] 


by true/false i meant it's either true or false, so just a boolean value. The problem lies in this params.permit(:boolean_value)[:boolean_value] because it doesn't return just true of false, it returns a strong parameters object which as you mentioned above results in true.
So for me it's either I skip the step with params.permit(:boolean_value)[:boolean_value] or I don't know how else I should handle it :(

something is missing here: ActionController::Parameters.new({"boolean_value": "true"}).permit(:boolean_value)[:boolean_value] #=> "true" returns the same string. also there is no need to permit when fetching individual values, just params[:boolean_value]

@Alex you are correct. Removed my update. ActionController::Parameters#[] only returns ActionController::Parameters if the value is a Hash. e.g. {boolean_value: {other: true}} then [:boolean_value] will return ActionController::Parameters otherwise it will simply return the value like a natural Hash would

@unnamed_road if params.permit(:boolean_value)[:boolean_value] returns a ActionController::Parameters object then there is a misalignment with the information presented in your original post. Can you confirm that the data structure in your post is actually representative of the problem?

Yeah, it's POST params I pass when making a request. The problem lies here ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.deserialize(params.permit(:boolean_value)[:boolean_value]) that when I pass boolean_value as false it still returns true

@unnamed_road can you post the actual logs showing the request parameters? Based on the question as posed what you are describing should not be possible so there must be some details missing.

You do not need to use strong parameters (ActionController::Parameters#permit) here in the first place. You're basically just doing { foo: "bar" }.slice(:foo)[:foo] which is quite redundant.
What strong parameters do is to avoid mass-assignment vulnerabilties where a malicous user adds an additional parameter to change something in the model they should not be able to. This vulnerabilty was famously used by Egor Holmakov to upload his own SSH key to Github and commit in the Rails repo.
ActionController::Parameters#permit just returns a new instance of ActionController::Parameters with the permitted flag set to true. Despite the popular misconceptions it does not do any typecasting or magical sanitation of the parameters.
If you're not actually performing mass assignment and just assigning a single parameter it's completely meaningless and this would acheive the exact same result:
ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.deserialize(params[:boolean_value])

But a less clunky way to deal with boolean values that won't bloat your controller is to just create a model:
class MyModel
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :boolean_value, :boolean
  attribute :string_value,  :string
  attribute :other_value,   :string
end

This is a "virtual" model that doesn't inherit from ActiveRecord::Base and is not stored in the database. But other from that it behaves just like a model.
You then just whitelist and assign the parameters just like you would with any other model.
MyModel.new(
  params.permit(:boolean_value, :string_value, :other_value)
)


thank you so much for such a great explanation!  The model work around doesn't fit my project exactly but other than that it helped to understand better, thanks again :)
